# Rotating UILabel that is under an UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, rotatetransform

I'm trying to rotate an UILabel that is under a (created on storyboard) UIView but it's crashing the application due nil value when I try to CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: ).
Is it causing because I'm using storyboard?

[image]

```
    @IBDesignable
    class AnalogView: UIView {

        @IBOutlet var prevPitch:UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var currectPitch:UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var nextPitch:UILabel!

        fileprivate let thickHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fileprivate let thinHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        fileprivate let roundThinLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: self)
        fileprivate let roundThickLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: self)

        @IBInspectable var thickYCoord: CGFloat = 50.0
        @IBInspectable var thinYCoord: CGFloat = 52.5



        @IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orange

        override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
            super.init(frame: frame)



            configure()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        }

        private func configure() {


            prevPitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.14)
```

Comment: please exact error message?

Comment: look at the debug area ( View / Debug Area / Show Debug Area  or  CMD+SHIFT+Y ) inspect the console there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this question by adding the labels with ViewController instead of the UIView.
Used `prevPitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.14)` on ViewController and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

your label `prevPitch` is not connected to your storyboard item

there is a plus instead of a circle on the left sidebar at your code.

you should reconnect it. maybe you lost this connection when you do a rename

Comment: Yes, it is. That's a plus because I let the mouse cursor above to highlight the connected label on the storyboard. I will try to reconnect it.

Comment: Update: Tried to reconnect and it's still crashing. As you can see, even @IBDesignable crashes.

Comment: did you look at the console to see why it crashes?